# For any Markov chain $X_n$, if the generator has $\mathscr{L}f \le -c$ for nonnegative $c$ then $f(X_n)+\sum_{i<n}c(X_i)$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

Let $(X_n,P_x)$ be a time homogeneous markov chain with one step transition kernel $\pi$. Denote the corresponding generator $$(\mathscr{L}f)(x) = (\pi f)(x)-f(x)=E_x[f(X_1)-f(X_0)]$$.

Then we know that $M_n^{[f]} = f(X_n)-\sum_{i<n} (\mathscr{L}f)(X_i)$ is a martingale w.r.t. $(\mathscr{F}_n^X)$ and $P_x$ for any $x$ and bounded measurable $f$.

Now, if the inequality $\mathscr{L}f\le -c$ holds for nonnegative measurable $f,c$, then why is the process
$$M_n^{[f,c]}= f(X_n)+\sum_{i<n}c(X_i)$$ a non-negative supermartingale?

$\mathscr{L}f \le -c$ is equivalent to $c \le -\mathscr{L}f$. We need to show that
$$E[f(X_n)+\sum_{i<n} c(X_i)|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]\le f(X_{n-1})+\sum_{i<n-1}c(X_i).$$

We have $E[f(X_n)+\sum_{i<n} c(X_i)|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]\le E[f(X_n)-\sum_{i<n} \mathscr{L}f(X_i)|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]=f(X_{n-1})-\sum_{i<n-1} \mathscr{L}f(X_i).$ But then $c \le -\mathscr{L}f$, so I can't get the RHS bound above. How do we show this? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take the following expectation and use the inequality:
$$\begin{aligned}E[M_{n}^{[f,c]}-(c(X_1)+c(X_2)+...+c(X_{n-2}))|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]&=E[f(X_n)|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]+c(X_{n-1})\leq\\
&\leq E[f(X_n)|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]-(\mathscr{L}f)(X_{n-1})=\\
&=f(X_{n-1})\\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\implies E[M_{n}^{[f,c]}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]\leq f(X_{n-1})+(c(X_1)+...+c(X_{n-2}))=M_{n-1}^{[f,c]}$$